# Primary ideals and radical of an ideal

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a regular local ring (for example, $R=\mathbb{C}\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$) and let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal in $R$.

Given an ideal $\mathfrak{a} \subset R$ such that $\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}=\mathfrak{p}$, when is $\mathfrak{a}$ a primary ideal?

(This is of course not true in general, but is there a nice way to know when is this true?)

Comment: Here's a simple one:  ${\mathfrak a} = {\mathfrak a}R_{\mathfrak p} \cap R$.  I'm not sure of what else one could do.

Comment: Another one: if $\mathfrak{p} = \sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}$ is the maximal ideal of $R$.

Comment: @pinaki What about when $\mathfrak{p}$ is of height $\dim(R)-1$? (That is, if we look at $\mathbb{C}\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$, then the case where $V(\mathfrak{p})$ is a curve).